# How to find widths of a Flat File using read_fwf() in Pandas?

Tags: pyspark, flat-file

I have downloaded some data from the Mainframe (.DATA format) and I need to parse it to create a PySpark DataFrame and perform some operations on it. Before doing that, I created a sample file and read it using read_fwf() feature of Pandas.

I was able to read and create the DataFrame but I encountered some problems like

1. Padding of "0" in the first column of some of the Rows
2. Repeating Headers while reading the Data

These were some of the issues I can handle, however the key challenge I am facing is in identifying the widths of the columns. I currently have 65 columns but in order to create a PySpark DataFrame, I would require to know the widths of these columns. Can read_fwf() tell what is the widths it is using for each column ?

And is there a read_fwf() like function in PySpark ? Or we would have to write a MapRed code for it ?

Comment: Can't you, as a first step create dataframe with all columns as `string` datatype and then do necessary type transformation?

Comment: That if fine, however I eventually want to create aPyspark dataframe for which I would need to know the widths for each column. Is there a way read_fwf returns the widths ?

Comment: @csingh1992 No. you should know width of each column before reading this file. Either you have to sepcify width of each column or start, end pos of each column. read_fwf does'nt assume anything. Refer to thi syntax.pandas.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer, colspecs='infer', widths=None, **kwds). If you have column width information you can import pandas package in spark and use read_fwf method.